# How do I specify to Zend Framework to use a different view file than the action default file?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have an action, successAction(), it uses the file in my views folder, success.phtml, how do I tell the action that I want it to use the success2.phtml file instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Zend_Controller_Action`'s `render`. This would render the view script in *controller-name/success2.phtml*

```
class ControllerName_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function successAction()
    {
        $this->render("success2");
    }
}
```

You should [read the docs on Zend Controller's](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->render('success2');
```